# SiteEdit doesn't work in my page

Tags: 2009, siteedit

I'd like to ask you something about my issue.

SiteEdit 2009 SP3 has been installed and configured for our website. We have followed the instructions provided in Chapter 2 Implementing and configuring SiteEdit in VBScript templates.

We have SiteEdit installed on port 91, SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 on port 90 and the staging website on port 88 (all in the same machine).

when I request this url:localhost:88//, SiteEdit is not enabled in my page.

I'm usinge the following code:

In the PT:

```
[%
    For Each lObjCP In Page.ComponentPresentations 
        WriteOut "<div>"
        WriteOut SiteEdit2.MarkComponentPresentation(lObjCP.ComponentID, 
            lObjCP.Component.Info.Version,lObjCP.ComponentTemplateID, "content",false) 
        WriteOut lObjCP.Content 
        WriteOut "</div>"
    Next     

    SiteEdit2.PageID = Page.ID
    SiteEdit2.PageVersion = Page.Info.Version
    WriteOut SiteEdit2.Finalize()
%]
```

In the CT:

```
[%
    WriteOut SiteEdit2.MarkComponentField(Component.Fields.item("Text").XPath) 
    WriteOut Replace(EscapeXMLCharacters(Component.Fields.item("Text").value(1)),
        vbCrLf, "<br>")
%]
```

This is the source of the published page:

```
<body>
    <html>
        <div>
            <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ID":"cp_1", "ComponentID":"tcm:27-3338", "ComponentVersion":2, "ComponentTemplateID":"tcm:27-3646-32", "IsQueryBased":true} -->
            <span>
                <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field: {"ID": "cf_1", "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:direccion", "IsMultiValued": false} -->wwewee </span>
        </div>
        <!-- SiteEdit Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:27-3186-64", "PageVersion":7, "ComponentPresentationLocation":1} -->
    </html>
</body>
```

Windows Server 2008 R2
IIS
SDLTridin 2011 SP1
SiteEdit 2009 SP3

Could you give me any ideas or solutions for this?

Comment: Could you look at the source of the published page, and let us know what SiteEdit code you see in the markup?

Comment: This is the source of the published page:
<body>
 <html>


<div><!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ID":"cp_1", "ComponentID":"tcm:27-3338", "ComponentVersion":2, "ComponentTemplateID":"tcm:27-3646-32", "IsQueryBased":true} --><span>
<!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field: {"ID": "cf_1", "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:direccion", "IsMultiValued": false} -->wwewee
</span></div><!-- SiteEdit Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:27-3186-64", "PageVersion":7, "ComponentPresentationLocation":1} -->


</html>
</body>

Comment: can you try http://localhost:91/ and post what you see?

Comment: Hi Pankaj,I thought the SiteEdit 2009 had the same functionality as the SiteEdit 1.3.

Comment: The functionality is very similar - The architecture is completely different.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if it is the cause of your issue, but having the `BODY` tag outside of the `HTML` tag seems very wrong. First step of getting SiteEdit to work is normally getting valid xhtml output.

Also you will never see SiteEdit on port 88 (the direct URL of your staging site). If the SiteEdit proxy is installed on port 91, that is the URL you should access. If you have configured it properly, you will then see the site served from port 88 with the extra SiteEdit layer added to it by the proxy layer on port 91.

Comment: I deleted <BODY> and <HTML> tags,i published the page,but the SiteEdit doesn't work.

Comment: Did you make the page valid xhtml or just delete the tags? Please validate your output with a tool like http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input - If it still doesn't work, please post any error messages in the body.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply. Site Edit is working in the port 91, but my staging site point to port 88.then,who to see the site served from port 88 with the extra SiteEdit layer added to it by the proxy layer on port 91?
I did these configurations:
In the file: %TRIDION_HOME%\SiteEdit 2009\Web.config, i updated the StagingUrl key with my staging website URL.
In the file: %TRIDION_HOME%\ SiteEdit 2009\SiteEdit\Application\Configuration SiteEdit.config,i updated the SmartTargetUrl with the Content Manager URL.
is necessary to make more configuarciones?

Comment: I am sorry - you message doesn't make much sense - SiteEdit is not supposed to work on the staging site URL - if you want SiteEdit to work on staging - you access it through the SiteEdit URL (not the staging URL). People only need to use the staging URL if they want to view the site without SiteEdit. What exactly is working on port 91?

Comment: Ok. I thought the SiteEdit 2009 had the same functionality as the SiteEdit 1.3. My last question is: when I request the URL: / / localhost: 91 / <domain> / <myPage>, it redirect to the page: / / localhost: 91/SiteEdit / # / <domain> / <myPage>. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes - that is correct

Comment: Perhaps you can accept/vote for this answer