# Cannot enable editing of Components with SiteEdit 2009 SP3

Tags: 2011, siteedit, vbscript

[image]SiteEdit 2009 SP3 has been installed and configured for our website. We have followed the instructions provided in chapter 2, Implementing and configuring SiteEdit in VBScript templates.

SiteEdit is enabled on the Page, but Components are not editable?

We have: Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS, SDL Tridin 2011 SP1 and SiteEdit 2009 SP3; and I'm using the following code in the PT:

```
[% 
    For Each lObjCP In Page.ComponentPresentations
        WriteOut "<div>"
        WriteOut SiteEdit2.MarkComponentPresentation(lObjCP.ComponentID, lObjCP.Component.Info.Version, lObjCP.ComponentTemplateID, "",true)
        WriteOut lObjCP.Content
        WriteOut "</div>"
    Next

    SiteEdit2.PageID = Page.ID
    SiteEdit2.PageVersion = Page.Info.Version
    WriteOut SiteEdit2.Finalize()                                     
%]
```

And in the CT:

```
[%
    WriteOut SiteEdit2.MarkComponentField(Component.Fields.item("Text").XPath) 
    WriteOut Replace(EscapeXMLCharacters(Component.Fields.item("Text").value(1)), vbCrLf, "<br>")
%]
```

this is part of the source of the published page:

```
<div>
    <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ID":"cp_1", "ComponentID":"tcm:7-474335", "ComponentVersion":4, "ComponentTemplateID":"tcm:7-648169-32", "IsQueryBased":true} -->
    <span>
        <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field: {"ID": "cf_1", "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:enlace/custom:texto", "IsMultiValued": false} -->
        This is a segund reportage
    </span>
</div>
<!-- SiteEdit Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:7-647740-64", "PageVersion":14, "ComponentPresentationLocation":1} -->
```

Could you give me any ideas or solutions for this?

I solved the problem by installing all the hotfixes.Thank you all for your colabroacion!

Comment: Can you add a sample of how the HTML of the published Page looks like, with the SiteEdit markup around your Component Presentation? Also you mention your Components are not editable, do you see a border appearing around the Component Presentation and the field, or is there nothing at all?

Comment: I added the source code above,the border doesn't appear,  is there nothing at all.

Comment: This way it is not readable what the source of your Page is, could you edit the question again and indent the source with 4 spaces (see how I formatted your template code already), that way stack exchange will leave all HTML intact there, it is very useful for us to see what HTML is around the SiteEdit markup and where the SiteEdit markup is placed in the page, without that it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: by the way, if this is still the same issue as in http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/site-edit-doesnt-work-in-my-page you should have updated that question rather than to make a new (duplicate) question

Comment: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/site-edit-doesnt-work-in-my-page and this post are different. I'm using VBScript Template because all our pages are devolved in VBScript

Comment: Given the PT and CT code and its outcome on the published Page, I don't see any issues. Did you check if there are any Javascript errors thrown on the page, which might interfere with SiteEdit?

Comment: This request: http://<domain>/SiteEdit/Process.aspx return this error: 401 Unauthorized 727ms.I checked with Firebug.

Comment: This request : http://<Domain>:SiteEdit/Models/SiteEditWebService.asmx/GetComponentsAndSchemas, return also the same error.

Comment: I don't get any javascript error,So could somebody suggest me the solutions or steps to fix it ?Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the limited information you give I'm unable to see what is going wrong. As for the steps on how to fix this, start from scratch with an empty Page, make sure that it is working in SiteEdit, then try adding a single Component Presentation and work from there. Trying to figure out a problem on a fully loaded Page with all bells and whistles can be impossible to debug at times. But be sure to double check that you have installed and configured the SiteEdit proxy as described in the manual too, the problem might not be in your Page, but in your setup.

Comment: The page I'm using now is a simple page that has only one Component Presentation and code I use is exactly the one I have attached arriba.SiteEdit is activated correctly, and connects well to CM, I can  open, add and publish page, I can also add existing component(attached screenshot). The only problem that  the editing of the component is not enable. I think the problem is in the HTTP  requests that are made to SiteEdit and not resolved correctly: 
401 Unauthorized

http://<Domain>/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/GetUserSettings
401 Unauthorized

Comment: Again try starting from scratch, first just have your Component Presentation contain a single word, and see if the border appears, then try enabling inline editing. I can't say much about the 401 errors, they are common in the process of authentication, you will first get a 401 and then the credentials in your session are sent through so a subsequent request should be sent which does return correctly. But if you think this is the problem, please add all this information in  clear way to your question, it makes no sense trying to add all this in comments.

Comment: Have you installed siteedit patch.

Comment: What patch are you taling about?

Comment: Are you using blueprinting? If so, make sure you've configured the blueprint structure in SE (chapter 2.6).

Answer (score 3):

Click on “border view” to see if the borders appear.  It could be that the elements have a higher Z index than the borders and floating over it or somehow the border is not wrapping correctly.  Check to see if a faint grey border appears anywhere on the screen.  That would mean its a shared item and you can not edit it without either localizing or clicking in "edit in parent" in the toolbar.

Also the html you provided is not consistent with what I see on the page.  You have a field with text "This is a segund reportage".  I don't see that text anywhere on that page.  Are you editing the right page?

Comment: I solved the problem by installing all the hotfixes.